# How can I subscribe to a different service method using a conditional statement?

Tags: angular, rxjs, subject-observer, rxjs-subscriptions

Can't figure out how to subscribe to the desired method of an Angular service depending on the conditional statement

```
  // this.someService.someMethod depending on the conditional statement
  .pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$))
  .subscribe((items) => {
    this.someData = items;
  });
```

Comment: UPD: For example I have a service with methods making http calls to the REST API and I have to make a different call depending on the current route.

Comment: How many different service methods are there? Do the methods return an observable? More context would be good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do following, if there might be different services to use:

```js
let source$: Observable<any>;

if ( conditionA ) {
  source$ = this.someService.someMethodA()
} else {
  source$ = this.someService.someMethodB()
}

source$
  .pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$))
  .subscribe((items) => {
    this.someData = items;
  });
```

or only saving method name if there is only one service to use. Also it depends on what is more readable to you.

```js
let methodName: string;

if ( conditionA ) {
  methodName = 'someMethodA';
} else {
  methodName = 'someMethodB';
}

this.someService[methodName]()
  .pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$))
  .subscribe((items) => {
    this.someData = items;
  });
```

Comment: That answer is actually good, because using the method name, you can call whatever you like. The problem might be only that refactoring method name will not work in some editors.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the RxJs Conditional Operator `iff` to achieve that if both of your services return an Observable or a Promise.

The `iff` operator takes 3 arguments, first when being your condition, 2nd and 3rd being your different services that return an Observable/Promise.

If the condition is `true` subscribe to the first `observable`, if it is `false` subscribe to the second `observable`

```
 iif(
      () => {
           //Add your condition here
           return a + b === 4;
         },
         this.someService.someMethodWhenTrue(),
         this.someService.someMethodWhenFalse()
     )
     .pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$))
     .subscribe((items)=> {
         this.someData = items;
     });
```

I recommend you to read this https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/conditional/iif